# Does any one have Gerhard Ringel's note: "Cyclic Arrangements of the elements of a group."

Tags: reference-request

Which has reference:

G. Ringel, 
Cyclic Arrangements of the elements of a group.
Notices of the American Mathematical Society 
Vol 21 1974 ​ pages A95-96​

I'm having a hard time getting a look at it. If you have it can you post or send me a pdf?

Cheers, Don

Comment: I always worry that I am saying this to someone who lives in Uzbekistan, but statistically it is usually good advice: What is the nearest university to you? Go to their library! Besides the fact that it will solve your problem, every person who comes helps the library committee make the case to the provost for more funds, which keeps the library running, and thus keeps good non-profit journals like Notices running.